# unknown at rule @tailwind css(unknownAtRules) tailwind error

Tags: tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5gP.jpg)

I AM NOT APPLICABLE TO SEE OUTPUT ON DISPLAY DUE TO THIS PROBLEM how can i fix this problem because i already give so much time to solve this problem so any one can give the solution of this problem

Answer (score 3):

You could look at installing the [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) and then:

> #### files.associations
>
> Use the files.associations setting to tell VS Code to always open `.css` files in Tailwind CSS mode:
>
> ```json
> "files.associations": {
>   "*.css": "tailwindcss"
> }
> ```

Otherwise, you could set `css.lint.unknownAtRules` VSCode setting to `ignore`.