TailwindCSS configuration in Vite React shows error in index.css file
I was starting my Vite React project. And as the next step I configured TailwindCSS as per Vite React documentation. Then I got this error message which targets the index.css file. The file only contained Tailwind CSS imports. How to solve this issue?
/* index.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

Error messages:

Unknown at rule @tailwind
Unknown at rule @tailwind
Unknown at rule @tailwind

I tried searching in the internet & connected some of my colleages. And they suggested me to retry the installation configuration or to ignore the error.

Not sure what the problem could be but you should follow the guide in the Tailwindcss docs on setting it up with vite: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite. I just set it up without hassle following the docs.

This question is similar to: unknown at rule @tailwind css(unknownAtRules) tailwind error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answer to this question, if you use VsCode, is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76777398/20929778


index.css
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

***Replace the index.css file configuration*** using the above given configuration.This will solve the problem.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

When I install Tailwind CSS with Vite, I add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers in my ./src/index.css file. Like this,
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

but i was getting the error messages
Unknown at rule @tailwind 

Unknown at rule @tailwind

Unknown at rule @tailwind

So, I change the file configuration of the index.css using this
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

And the problem/error get solved, the vite project is running without any issues.
